# Error when linking library in react native

Tags: android, react-native

When i run `react-native link` give this error

> Something went wrong while linking.
>
> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\ ...{MY_APP_NAME}\android \app\src\main\java\com{MY_APP_NAME}\android\MainApplication.java'

Comment: Are you using Expo?

Comment: MainApplication.java file exists in your {MY_APP_NAME} folder and not inside android folder ...try manual installation

Comment: No, I dont use Expo @Andrew

Comment: @MahdiBashirpour how did you solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The application is expecting a file  at

> D:\ ...{MY_APP_NAME}\android
>   \app\src\main\java\com{MY_APP_NAME}\android\MainApplication.java

but that file does not exist (which is what ENOENT means). So you either haver to create the expected directory structure or else configure your application such that it looks in the correct directory.

Comment: Which files does `react-native link` use to find MainApplication.java?  Trying to figure out how to change the path to match our structure, not the other way around.

I'm expecting `./android/app/src/main/java/com/{MY_APP_NAME}/app/MainApplication.java` but getting `./android/app/src/main/java/com/com/{MY_APP_NAME}/app/MainApplication.java` instead.  The app id of the app is `com.{MY_APP_NAME}.app`